# How to solve AAPT2 error in android studio?

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

when I run my project with **assembleDebug** , I get this error

```
:app:mergeDebugResources
C:\Users\Deepan\Downloads\googleads-mobile-android-examples- 
master\googleads-mobile-android-examples-master\java\admob\NativeAdvancedExample\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-sw600dp-v13\values-sw600dp-v13.xml: error: file not found.
Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
:app:mergeDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and moving entire project to another location where the path is shorter solved it. You also have a quite long path.

Answer (score 0):

File ***values-sw600dp-v13.xml***

is missing from ***values-sw600dp-v13*** folder.

past the file in ***values-sw600dp-v13*** and it should work.